# Pandas cumulative sum reset based on percentage of the last checkpoint

Tags: python, pandas

Sample Data

```
date_rng = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', freq='s', periods=400)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.lognormal(.005, .5, size=(len(date_rng))),
                  columns=['data1'],
                  index=date_rng)
```

Example input

```
                    data1
2019-01-01 00:00:00 1
2019-01-01 00:00:01 -2
2019-01-01 00:00:02 2
2019-01-01 00:00:03 3
2019-01-01 00:00:04 1
2019-01-01 00:00:05 2
2019-01-01 00:00:06 -1
2019-01-01 00:00:07 3
2019-01-01 00:00:08 4
2019-01-01 00:00:09 5
2019-01-01 00:00:10 7
2019-01-01 00:00:11 2
2019-01-01 00:00:12 4
2019-01-01 00:00:13 -1
2019-01-01 00:00:14 5
2019-01-01 00:00:15 3
2019-01-01 00:00:16 5
2019-01-01 00:00:17 -3
... ...
```

Expected output

```
                    data1 cumsum
2019-01-01 00:00:00 1     1
2019-01-01 00:00:01 -2    -1
2019-01-01 00:00:02 2     1
2019-01-01 00:00:03 3     4
2019-01-01 00:00:04 1     5 (reset cumsum at this point)
2019-01-01 00:00:05 2     2
2019-01-01 00:00:06 -1    1
2019-01-01 00:00:07 3     4
2019-01-01 00:00:08 4     8 (reset at this point)
2019-01-01 00:00:09 5     5 (reset at this point)
2019-01-01 00:00:10 7     7 (reset at this point)
2019-01-01 00:00:11 2     2
2019-01-01 00:00:12 4     6 (reset at this point)
2019-01-01 00:00:13 -1    -1
2019-01-01 00:00:14 5     4
2019-01-01 00:00:15 3     7 (reset at this point)
2019-01-01 00:00:16 1     1
2019-01-01 00:00:17 -3    -2
... ...
```

I want to calculate the cumulative sum of the `data1` based on the condtiontion that it will reset if it larger than 5 and exceed 20% of the last reset. For example: for the first calculation, it will only reset if it's larger than 5, after that, it will reset based on both conditions.

I have checked out some other answers on stackoverflow but I didn't find similar problems. Please advice me on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Please share a sample input and expected output.

Comment: I have added both of those

Comment: so, you want to create a new column, and the value of the each row of `cumsum` corresponds to one specific row of `data1` exactly?

Comment: @ThanhNguyen, when you say "it exceeds 20% of last reset", what does that exactly mean?

Comment: @thushv89 for example, in case that the `cumsum` reach value of 27, the cumulative sum will be calculated from the next row, and this time if the `cumsum` is larger than `27*20%`, the calculation will reset again

Comment: Let's take second cumsum window in your example, according to your logic, it should reset when it hits value (5*0.2 = 1)? But it has only reset at 8?

Comment: I know how to solve it by implementation, but i'm looking for a more pythonic way :D

Comment: @thushv89 you can see that there are two conditions: larger than 5 and larger than 20% of the last reset. The `cumsum` need to satisfy both so that the calculation can reset.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `loop`  with `if else` and some logic to solve this problem.

```
ls = []  # store result
cumsum = 0
last_reset = 0
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    cumsum = cumsum + row.data1
    ls.append(cumsum)
    if cumsum >= 5 and cumsum > 0.2*last_reset:
        last_reset = cumsum
        cumsum = 0

df['cumsum'] = ls

df
                     data1  cumsum
2019-01-01 00:00:00      1       1
2019-01-01 00:00:01     -2      -1
2019-01-01 00:00:02      2       1
2019-01-01 00:00:03      3       4
2019-01-01 00:00:04      1       5
2019-01-01 00:00:05      2       2
2019-01-01 00:00:06     -1       1
2019-01-01 00:00:07      3       4
2019-01-01 00:00:08      4       8
2019-01-01 00:00:09      5       5
2019-01-01 00:00:10      7       7
2019-01-01 00:00:11      2       2
2019-01-01 00:00:12      4       6
2019-01-01 00:00:13     -1      -1
2019-01-01 00:00:14      5       4
2019-01-01 00:00:15      3       7
2019-01-01 00:00:16      1       1
2019-01-01 00:00:17     -3      -2
```

Comment: thanks for your great answer, however I still looking for a more efficient calculation, since my data contains of million of lines

Comment: If your data are ordered correctly, you can use `df.data1.tolist()` instead of `iterrows`.